# Web capture like adobe acrobat pro?

Tags: software-recommendation, pdf

I'm looking for something Ubuntu that compares to web-capture in adobe acrobat pro. It's a feature that asks for a url, whether to follow links, and if so how many levels to follow. It then goes to the website, and imports the links into a pdf.

I need this feature, if it's available, in Ubuntu. What I'm needing to do is to type in a url that has nothing but links to tiff document images, all the pages to the document being on that page.  I can't find a way to automate the process of getting and importing into pdf.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: you can get adobe acrobat pro for linux from adobe

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind working in terminal:

- use `wget` to download all the images. They syntax would depend on the actual page. use `man wget` to see the options.
- use ImageMagick's `convert` program to convert all the images to a single pdf file:

  ```
  convert -define pdf:use-trimbox=true *.tiff output.pdf
  ```

Once you figure this out, you could wrap the commands into a nice reusable script.